# Macro that is true only when the compiler starts a build

Tags: c++, macros, intellisense

Is it possible to have a macro be set to `true` when building but otherwise is set to `false`? I realize there are macros to detect build configurations (e.g. debug/release) but I am looking for a macro that is set when the compiler starts building. It's okay if the macro is very specific to a particular compiler.

The use case is to help intellisense with some complex macros by simplifying them. The autocomplete does not work with the complex macros. However the simplified macros are very slow at runtime.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 not true, Microsoft's Intellisense does its own parsing while you edit.

Comment: I know such a macro exists, because I've used it. But I don't have the code in front of me to look at.

Comment: @MarkRansom ah that makes sense. My first idea was at runtime, I am not used to fancy IDEs

Comment: You might want to use a [hint file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/hint-files?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 1):

This one would probably work:

```cpp
#define ONLY_TRUE_AT_COMPILE_TIME true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a macro in your IDE and don't use it in the build process

```
#ifdef IDE_MACRO
    #define SIMPLE_MACROS
#else
    #define COMPLEX_MACROS
#endif
```

In Visual Studio Code you can set

```
"configurations": [
{
   ...
   "defines":[
       "IDE_MACRO"
   ]
}
]
```

in

```
.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
```

> *defines* A list of preprocessor definitions for the IntelliSense engine
>   to use while parsing files. Optionally, use = to set a value, for
>   example VERSION=1.

This only works if compileCommands is not set

> *compileCommands (optional)* The full path to the compile_commands.json
>   file for the workspace. The include paths and defines discovered in
>   this file will be used instead of the values set for includePath and
>   defines settings. If the compile commands database does not contain an
>   entry for the translation unit that corresponds to the file you opened
>   in the editor, then a warning message will appear and the extension
>   will use the includePath and defines settings instead.

As you can read in the quote you can also use `compile_commands.json` to set macros and IntelliSense will consider them.

In Eclipse CDT it's in *C/C++ Build* -> *Build Variables*. There you can set a Variable `IDE_MACRO`. Now Eclipse CDT uses `SIMPLE_MACROS` instead of `COMPLEX_MACROS`. In the build process the macro `IDE_MACRO` is not defined and the compiler uses `COMPLEX_MACROS`.